# Prevent TextBox from firing on enter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I am working with `Ajax` to retrieve information from database without refreshing the page. I have a `asp:TextBox` that firing the `Ajax` event with `TextChanged` (when I lose focus from the `TextBox`). Now, I want to disable the option to click enter it in because then it calls the `Ajax` event, but also refreshing the page for some reason. I managed to disable it if text hasn't changed by adding an attribute of `OnKeyDown` to it. But, when I change the text and instantly press enter, the page gets refreshed. I tried adding `OnKeyPress` too, but it seems to have no effect. How can I fix this issue?

```js
function cancel_enter(elem) {
    if (window.event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("btnReg").focus();
        document.getElementById("btnReg").click();
        if (elem != null)
            elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
    return true;
}
```

```html
<asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server" />
<table dir="rtl" style="text-align:left;" id="table_user" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"><ContentTemplate><asp:TextBox TextMode="SingleLine" ID="reg_user" runat="server" MaxLength="50" OnTextChanged="reg_user_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox></ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my codebehind. I add the attribute in there:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    reg_user.Attributes.Add("OnKeyDown", "return cancel_enter(this);");
}
```

Comment: You can try to wrap the text box in a Panel and set the DefaultButton of the panel to a certain invisible button whose UseSubmitBehavior property is set to false. This is a raw approach which you can work on to enhance it.

Comment: I thought of it too. I will surely try that soon enough! Thanks.